# How to prevent printing error message 401 (Unauthorized) in console?

Tags: angular, typescript

When the user does not enter the correct credentials the following error appears.

[image]

I am already treating the error and do not want this to print out to the debug window.

My code:

-------------auth.service.ts-------------

```html
 login(user: User) {

    return this.http.post(this.config.getBaseUrl()+'oauth/token', user, this.config.getHeader())
      .map(res => res.json());

  }
```

-------------login.component.ts-------------

```html
login() {
    this.authService.login(this.user).subscribe(
            result => console.log(result),
            error => console.log(error)
    );
```

How can I prevent this error from printing out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not something angular do. It is  a functionality of the browser. you cannot remove it by changing your client side code.

Comment: got it

I will not bother with this error.
thought what the angular solve this error.


thank you!